# r reshape data using row with NA to identify new column

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataset in R that looks like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(name=c("A","b","c","d","B","e","f"),
                 x=c(NA,1,2,3,NA,4,5))
```

I would like to reshape it into:

```
rDF <- data.frame(name=c("b","c","d","e","f"),
                  x=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  head=c("A","A","A","B","B"))
```

where the first row with an `NA` identifies a new column, and takes that "row value" until the next row with an `NA`, and then changes "row value".

I have tried both `spread` and `melt`, but it does not give me what I want.

```
library(tidyr)
DF %>% spread(name,x)
library(reshape2)
melt(DF, id=c('name'))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @user20650 why did you delete your solution?

Comment: @DavidArenburg; it was the same as Colonel's... no point cluttering up the page ;)

Comment: @user20650 But you posted first and you didn't use packages. I must say that you are my role model on how to behave on SO.

Comment: haha... cheers David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table`/`zoo` packages combination solution

```
library(data.table) ; library(zoo)

setDT(DF)[is.na(x), head := name]
na.omit(DF[, head := na.locf(head)], "x")

#    name x head
# 1:    b 1    A
# 2:    c 2    A
# 3:    d 3    A
# 4:    e 4    B
# 5:    f 5    B
```

Or as suggested by @Arun, just using `data.table`

```
na.omit(setDT(DF)[, head := name[is.na(x)], by=cumsum(is.na(x))])
```

Comment: what'd be really cool here is to have something like `setDT(DF)[is.na(x), head := name, roll=TRUE]`...

Comment: @Arun or `roll=na.locf` maybe? I think I saw this somewhere recently

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

split(DF, cumsum(is.na(DF$x))) %>%
    lapply(function(u) transform(u[-1,], head=u[1,1])) %>% 
    rbindlist

#   name x head
#1:    b 1    A
#2:    c 2    A
#3:    d 3    A
#4:    e 4    B
#5:    f 5    B
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using only base R functions:

```
idx <- is.na(DF$x)
x <- rle(cumsum(idx))$lengths
DF$head <- rep(DF$name[idx], x)
DF[!idx,]
#  name x head
#2    b 1    A
#3    c 2    A
#4    d 3    A
#6    e 4    B
#7    f 5    B
```